# regex with several strings and values

Tags: regex

I've been trying to learn regex recently but am struggling just now. Here are 3 strings I need to match. I'm trying to create a regex that does it in one:

```
Paypal Purchase Complete Promo Unlimited Pears
Paypal Purchase CompleteUnlimited Pears
Paypal Purchase Complete Unlimited Pears
```

So there may or may not be a space between CompleteUnlimited and there may or may not exist "Promo" between Complete and Unlimited.

I tried this:

```
^Paypal Purchase Complete ?(Promo)?Unlimited Pears$
```

But when I checked that on the regex testers in top results of Google "Regex tester" it did not match?

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^Paypal Purchase Complete ?(Promo )?Unlimited Pears$

                                 ^^
```

You were missing a `space`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0iN5/6